# MERGE with Sequential Numbering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with several fields which includes a column called apporder which is just an integer.  The value is used for the order in which it is displayed on the front end.  So it would be like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I am trying to merge new values into that table, and each new insert should be 1 higher than the max.

This is what I am trying, but it is always inserting the max value + 1 from the table, not taking into account any new rows inserted.  How can I accomplish this.

```
MERGE INTO table2 USING
    (SELECT field1,field2,apporder FROM table1) a ON a.field1 = table2.field1
WHEN NOT MATCHED TEHN
    INSERT
        (
            field1,
            field2,
            apporder
        )
    VALUES
        (
            'a',
            'b',
            (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(apporder),0) + 1 FROM table2)
        )
```

Comment: Do you mean it does not take into account the extra value on the same insert statement?  So if 2 values are in the one merge and the value should be 4 then 5 for next one (on same insert), you could have to update your query to account for that before the merge, or loop through the records to do one at a time.

Comment: Say the current max value in the table is 4.  I am inserting 2 new rows, so they would be 4 and 5 respectively.

Comment: ok, so i would account for that in my USING select statement.  How do I do that, wouldnt it just give me the same result?

Comment: If the max value is 4, and you want to insert 4 and 5, won't you have a duplicate value? Why not use an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: i think you're kinda smoked, because if you create a counter column in the source table, some of the rows might match so for your insert you will get a broken series like, 1, 2, 5. If that's not a problem, then go ahead. ANOTHER reason to avoid merge like plague

Comment: sorry i meant 5 then 6

Comment: @siggemannen better then a cursor

Comment: Trying to maintain a sequence this way is subject to concurrency race conditions, use the robust sequence or identity options already provided by the database for free.

Comment: @Stu what is the robust sequence?  I cant use identity

Comment: Alternatively don't store a sequence at all just create it in a view or tvf using a row_number partition ordered by your PK or Createdate etc

Comment: you can use UPDATE + INSERT, that would simplify your work a lot

Comment: @siggemannen i simplified the merge.  It is actually a lot more complicated

Comment: *" I cant use identity "* why not? It's both what you want and need.

Comment: @ThomA because it is grouped.  So I can have the same number more than 1.  Group A would have 1, 2, 3, 4.  Group B could have 1,2,3,4.  And so on

Comment: Could I use NEXT VALUE FOR somehow?

Comment: That isn't apparent in your question, @dk96m . Sample data and expected results are king.

Comment: Do you have a *known* number of groups?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want some kind of numbering column grouped by `field1`. But `MERGE` does not do this, it simply identifies a single matching row if any, and updates or inserts it. Instead just use a normal `INSERT`.

To do this without running into concurrency problems, you are going to need the `UPDLOCK` and `SERIALIZABLE` hints on the subquery. You are going to end up locking each complete group, and obviously you will get holes if anyone deletes a row.

You also need to take into account multiple rows being inserted at once. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this.

```sql
INSERT table2
  (field1, field2, apporder)
SELECT
  t1.field1,
  t1.field2,
  (
   SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t2.apporder), 0)
   FROM table2 t2 WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
   WHERE t2.field1 = t1.field1
  ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.field1 ORDER BY t1.field2)
FROM table1 t1;
```

If possible, you should just forgo this column completely, and instead calculate it using `ROW_NUMBER` when you query the table

```sql
SELECT
  t2.field1,
  t2.field2,
  apporder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.field1 ORDER BY t1.field2)
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.field1 = 'something';
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you provided, I am assuming that you first need to get the maximum apporder value from table2 and increment it by 1 then include that value in the INSERT statement when inserting the new rows and make sure that they will always be inserted with a value higher than the current maximum value, even if new rows have been inserted concurrently.

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
  field1 VARCHAR(255),
  field2 VARCHAR(255),
  apporder INT
);

CREATE TABLE YourTable2 (
  field1 VARCHAR(255),
  field2 VARCHAR(255),
  apporder INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (field1, field2, apporder)
VALUES
  ('Data 1', 'Value 1', 1),
  ('Data 2', 'Value 2', 2),
  ('Data 3', 'Value 3', 3),
  ('Data 4', 'Value 4', 4);
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO YourTable2 (field1, field2, apporder)
VALUES
  ('Data 1', 'Value 1', 10),
  ('Data 2', 'Value 2', 22),
  ('Data 6', 'Value 3', 35),
  ('Data 5', 'Value 4', 42);
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
MERGE INTO YourTable2 AS tgt
USING (
  SELECT field1, field2, MAX(apporder) AS maxAppOrder
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY field1, field2
) AS src ON tgt.field1 = src.field1 AND tgt.field2 = src.field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (field1, field2, apporder)
  VALUES (src.field1, src.field2, src.maxAppOrder + 1);
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
SELECT * FROM YourTable2
```

| field1 | field2 | apporder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Value 1 | 1 |
| Data 2 | Value 2 | 2 |
| Data 3 | Value 3 | 3 |
| Data 4 | Value 4 | 4 |

| field1 | field2 | apporder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Value 1 | 10 |
| Data 2 | Value 2 | 22 |
| Data 6 | Value 3 | 35 |
| Data 5 | Value 4 | 42 |
| Data 3 | Value 3 | 4 |
| Data 4 | Value 4 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V6HQ3T28)